Targeting Using Python in FPS Games
I have detected enemies and have coordinates for them in python but I just can't figure out how to move the mouse to those coordinates. In the FPS game I am playing, when you equip a weapon, it locks your mouse to a set of coordinates (the center). While I have the coordinates for the enemy players, when I am focused into the game with the weapon equipped, the program can't move the mouse to those coordinates so it doesn't work. However, it works perfectly fine if the mouse isn't locked, so if I unequip my weapon, it will move the mouse towards the enemy just fine. No idea how FPS games work and how mouse actions are detected. Is there a way I can use python to fix this?
Here is a snippet of code so you have a general idea of what I am trying to achieve
frame = camera.grab(region=region)
enemy = process_frame(frame)

if enemy:
  print(enemy, frame[enemy[1]][enemy[0]])
  mouse.move(enemy[0], enemy[1], absolute=True)

  time.sleep(0.05)

